# Unable to Get XPath for WhitePages.com?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to enter a name and zip code in the `"People"` and `"Where"` fields on `http://whitepages.com` using Selenium (in Java).

I  have tried using `.//*[@id='who']` and `.//*[@id='where']` respectively - however Selenium throws an error each time I run the program.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow alexce.  Feedback for your 1st question: Can you give some example errors, or the Selenium test code you used in your testing (that is, not just the `id` codes also but the actual test class you wrote, or a link to it in github/bitbucket/wherever)?  This will help people to review/replicate what may be going wrong -- it also shows that you're putting in a bit more effort rather than just crying to the web winds, and that too will make it more likely for someone to answer your question.

Comment: @mike - I got my answer. Why make a comment like this on a question already answered ? Are you trying to build you rep my reducing mine?

Comment: Nope, I'm just failing at Review, obviously :-/. Sorry. It came up in the First Posts list, with no answers shown there.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here is that *there are multiple elements with `id="who"`*. Use a CSS selector to locate the desired one inside the "search" form:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.callerid-skin #header form[role=search] #who"));
```

You may also need to [explicitly wait for the field to become visible](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.callerid-skin #header form[role=search] #who")));
```

Comment: I observed the same. This just makes automation more harder. You would think the id is unique.

Comment: @Saifur right, you can see it from time to time. Here, it looks like it's just multiple "skins" loaded at the same time making multiple elements having the same id. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - Thanks. May I ask how you arrived at this CSS path? I am using Firebug and when I hover over the "People" element it just shows "#who" - where did you get the entire path from (i.e, ""div.callerid-skin #header form[role=search]")?

Comment: @SamTin I've experimented with the CSS selector inspecting the element's parents one by one trying to locate the unique path for the element. I'm sure you can write a better and simpler one here though. The point is, you need to be more specific while reaching the element.

Comment: @alecxe - so there is no simple way of doing this?

Comment: @SamTin like make smth generate the selector or xpath expression for you? Well, firebug can do this, but it would be the absolute expression starting from the very parent element.

Answer (score 0):

It has many elements with id='where' in which many are hidden thats why it is throwing exceptions for you. Try to locate visible elements using specific locator

For People (@id='who') use below locator

```
By.cssSelector("#header[style] #who[data-gaaction*='people']")
```

For Where (@id='where') use below locator

```
By.cssSelector("#header[style] #where[data-gaaction*='business']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebug, there are multiple choices to get an element path:
1. inspect the element (HTML tab should be active)
2. Right click on the element (from HTML source) and you will see multiple options:
- Copy XPath
- Copy minimal XPath
- Copy CSS Path

For problematic elements, you can paste in Notepad++ all 3 paths and experiment a little. It might save you some time, instead of starting from the up-most parent and narrowing down on a shorter path.